# Existe alguma diferença entre strtr() e str_replace()?

Tags: php, string, funções

Estava analisando a maneira como se comportam as funções `strtr()` e `str_replace()` e reparei que, a primeira vista, as duas parecem fazer exatamente a mesma coisa.
Exemplo:

```
$translators = [
    'da hora' => 'bacana',
    'ser' => 'é',
];

$str = 'O Stack Overflow ser um site da hora';

echo str_replace(array_keys($translators), $translators, $str);
//  O Stack Overflow é um site bacana
    
echo strtr($str, $translators);
//O Stack Overflow é um site bacana
```

Tirando a forma com que são passados os parâmetros das funções, existem alguma diferença considerável entre elas, a ponto de ter que decidir qual usar para cada caso específico?

Ou as duas fazem a mesma coisa?

E, se fazem, por que de existir as duas?

Comment: vê se isso ajuda você: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace caso não entenda, solicite que formato uma resposta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essencialmente elas fazem a mesma coisa, mas com diferentes resultados em certas situações e com diferentes compromissos de velocidade.

`strtr` é um pouco mais rápido para operações simples e `str_replace` se dá melhor para operações mais complexas, segundo as respostas para [essa pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7620549/221800).

Além disto há diferença no funcionamento segundo [esse comentário](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#91536) na documentação:

```
<?php 
$arrFrom = array("1","2","3","B"); 
$arrTo = array("A","B","C","D"); 
$word = "ZBB2"; 
echo str_replace($arrFrom, $arrTo, $word) . "\n"; //ZDDD

$arr = array("1" => "A","2" => "B","3" => "C","B" => "D"); 
$word = "ZBB2"; 
echo strtr($word,$arr); //ZDDB
?>
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qguAj8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TrReplace). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/StrReplace.php).

Comment: Ou `$arr = array_combine($arrFrom, $arrTo)` :)

Comment: Isso vem provavelmente do fato que, em PHP, não tem "array" como o que achamos (como em C por exemplo). O pior exemplo na minha opinião e o comportamento de "implode".(obrigado Wallace)

Comment: @bigowm, analisando as duas situações, me parece que o `strtr` é "melhor" em termos de precisão. Pelo que entendi, o `str_replace` parece "varrer" tudo de forma sequencial, de acordo com a ordem do array, causando a "substituição do que foi substituído". antigamente, eu iria usar o `preg_replace` só por conta disso!

Comment: Não gosto muito dizer melhor a não ser que seja claramente melhor :) Mas pode-se dizer que sim. Para coisas simples qualquer tentativa de uso de expressão regular fatalmente será mais lento.

Answer (score 7):

Do [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) verifica uma string `subject` por presença de uma string `search` e substitui esta string por `replace`.

[strtr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php) verifica em uma string `str` por presença de uma string `from` e substitui **cada caractere** de `from` para o caractere correspondente de `to`. Se os comprimentos de `from` e `to` são diferentes, os caracteres extras da mais longa são ignorados.