# Remover Acentos e Transformar espaços em traços PHP

Tags: php, string, mysqli, acentuação

Atualizei meu PHP e meu seguinte Script a qual eu utilizava para transformar o texto sem acentos, e os espaços em traços (-) não funciona mais no PHP devido o **ereg_replace** está obsoleto.

```
<?php
    $variavel = "Céu Azul";
    $variavel_limpa = strtolower( ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($variavel)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ"),"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );
    echo $variavel_limpa; // ceu-azul
?>
```

Qual seria a solução para mim realizar a transformação desta string (retirando acentos e colocando traço entre os espaços) para funcionar no PHP 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php), suportado no PHP 7 também.:

```
$variavel_limpa = strtolower( preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($variavel)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ"),"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );
```

> É preciso também incluir os delimitadores `//` na regex.

**[Teste aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e81bc4d768e480ef2a14a851709012f0bb28eafc)**

Comment: Olá amigo @dvd funcionou muito bem! Antes da sua edição estava sem "-" entre os espaços. agora funcionou!

Comment: É que havia esquecido do detalhe dos delimitadores. Valeu!

Answer (score 5):

Como o `ereg_replace` foi deprecado, é necessário substituir por outra função. No lugar dessa função, você pode utilizar `preg_replace`, o funcionando é bem semelhante e as regras — praticamente — são iguais.

Para remover os caracteres com acentos, você pode utilizar a função `iconv`, assim você irá "traduzir" algumas letras, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$text = "O céu azul foi visto por André, João…";

/**
 * Converte a String para ASCII
 * O //TRANSLIT irá tentar traduzir os caracteres, por exemplo è => "`e"
 * Após isso, aplicamos uma expressão regular para deixar somente 
 * \w = Números, Letras e "underline"; e \s = espaço
 */
$text = preg_replace("/[^\w\s]/", "", iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text));

/* Com o str_replace podemos substituir os espaços 
 * deixados na linha anterior, pelo hífen
 */
$text = str_replace(" ", "-", $text);

/* Transformamos todo o texto em minúsculo */
$text = strtolower($text);


echo $text;
// Output: o-ceu-azul-foi-visto-por-andre-joao
```

<sup>Demonstração: https://ideone.com/0VC8tb</sup>

Comment: Funcionou muito bem! Obrigado!

Comment: Pois esta a resposta que aponta o melhor caminho, do qual faz uma "checagem" dos caracteres, seja ANSI (ios-8859-1 ou windows-1252) seja utf-8, transcreve em ASCII se possivel e o que não é possivel você elimina com os metacaracteres, fazendo ser algo funcional, diferente do `utf8_encode` que sempre espera UTF-8 e que não vai resolver "qualquer entrada". Não estou afirmando que é 100% infalível, pode até "comer" algumas letras, mas é um recurso interno bem mais eficiente que montar um range `àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ` e usar utf8_decode. +1

Answer (score 1):

[**strtolower**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php) - Converte uma string para minúsculas

[**strtr**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php) - traduz determinados caracteres em uma string

[**utf8_decode**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php) - converte uma string com caracteres ISO-8859-1 codificadas com UTF-8 para single-byte ISO-8859-1.

```
$variavel = "Céu Azul";
$variavel_limpa = strtolower(strtr(utf8_decode($variavel), utf8_decode('àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ '), 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY-'));
```

[**exemplo - PHP Sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb1f716fea3c3cb463719050d2c483aafbe150b4)

> `strtr` e `str_replace`, essencialmente fazem a mesma coisa, sendo que `strtr` é um pouco mais rápido para operações simples.

Para coisas simples qualquer tentativa de uso de expressão regular fatalmente será mais lento. [**Fonte**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52332/existe-alguma-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-strtr-e-str-replace/52335#52335)